# Maintain an object reference when writing to parcel in Android

Tags: android, android-intent, parcelable, intentservice, parcel

I have a class that extends ResultReceiver. When I start my main activity, on the onCreate method, I call an IntentService to fetch some data from the internet.

Since I need the service to pass Movie objects to the main activity, I need to instantiate the ResultReceiver in the activity and pass it to the service.

```
final class MovieResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    private static final String MOVIE_ARRAY = "movie array";
    private static final int RESULT_SUCCESS= 101000;


    private ResultProcessor mProcessor;

    MovieResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }


    interface ResultProcessor {
        void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
    }

    void setReceiver(ResultProcessor resultProcessor) {
        mProcessor = resultProcessor;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        if (mProcessor != null) {
            mProcessor.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }
    }


    void notifyReceiver(Bundle bundle, Parcelable[] parcelables) {
        bundle.putParcelableArray(MOVIE_ARRAY,parcelables);
        send(RESULT_SUCCESS,bundle);
    }


    private MovieResultReceiver(Parcel in) {
        super(new Handler());
    }

    static final Creator<MovieResultReceiver> CREATOR = new Creator<MovieResultReceiver>() {
        @Override
        public MovieResultReceiver createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new MovieResultReceiver(source);
        }

        @Override
        public MovieResultReceiver[] newArray(int size) {
            return new MovieResultReceiver[0];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        // I need to pass a reference to MainActivity, 
        // so I need to write it to the parcel somehow
    }
}
```

The ResultProcessor member variable will be set to my Main Activity, because it will use the data that the service will fetch.

My question is:

How can I maintain a reference to the main activity when I pass the ResultReceiver as an intent extra?

What do I need to "write to parcel"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this and it is right because `Parcel` is time independent object - it can be restored even after an `Activity` is recreated, so the reference to it will change.

You can pass a reference to the Main Activity via `Application` object or some static field. That field will be initialized in activity's `onCreate` and used while reading data from parcel.